# how to use htaccess code for url rewrite in php for dynamic page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

```
<a class='btn btn-success' href='search.php?subbutton1=$searchid'>View More</a>
<a href='". $row["website_link"]. "' class='btn btn-success'>Visit Website</a>
```

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?:.*?)\\/?([0-9]+)\\-[\\d\\w\\s\\-]+\\/?
```

Comment: <a  class='btn btn-success'   href='search.php?subbutton1=$searchid' >View More</a></td><td><a href='". $row["website_link"]. "' class='btn btn-success'>Visit Website</a>

Comment: this is my php code

Comment: @mohd_asif Please explain what you want to do, what you tried, and what you need. Nobody can guess it if you just (badly) paste your code...

Comment: ....and provide examples of the input and expected output

Comment: my url open just like http://localhost/yamunaexpresswayprojects.com/search.php?subbutton1=$projectname;

Comment: but i want open this like http://localhost/yamunaexpresswayprojects.com/$project

Comment: its is dynamic url